# Give less reputation on answers when question is marked as duplicate

Tags: feature-request, reputation, duplicate-questions, up-votes

We always come across questions that are duplicate. If a question already has comment that it is possible duplicate. Then, I always check if that is the correct duplicate and if yes, I flag it as duplicate. But I also see people posting same answers as earlier.

Those answers get upvotes and reputation, even though same answers are already posted in the other questions.

I suggest that after the question is marked duplicate (e.g. after second or third vote while question is still open) answers posted on that question will give less reputation to their author when voted up, e.g. 5 points instead of 10.

Comment: You don't get any points for flagging. You *do* get the warm feeling that you helped making Stack Overflow a better place.

Comment: What exactly is your feature request?

Comment: @Wooble : I mentioned that more clearly now.

Comment: Must admit there is some sense in this, I see people copying answers from linked duplicates and getting easy points.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Are you suggesting that answering duplicate answer must be discouraged altogether..?

Comment: How would this work when the duplicate link is wrong and the question is reopened?

Comment: @CRUSADER yes, same way that answering bad questions that end up closed for other reasons is not encouraged. To keep it organized, if one got something new to add, best course of action is to add this as new answer on the original question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters good point. Guess it can cause recalculation, giving full points again. :)

Comment: This rather overcomplicates things, though, doesn't it? Not to mention an incentive to perhaps subtly edit the question to make it a unique question..

Comment: @Sha Flag -> other -> "this answer is plagiarized word-for-word from this other answer" -> delete

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd `best course of action is to add this as new answer on the original question`..What?? And as Martijn Pieters commented, what if the original question gets deleted, then all answers be transferred as well??

Comment: @MartijnPieters : This is where a rule/feature will be helpful.

Comment: @Cody possible, but many will still slip through and there are cases when users won't copy word by word but still use the same idea, giving nothing new.

Comment: @CRUSADER Take [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/447356) for example. Two months after it was posted, [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/523643/447356) was posted and closed as duplicate within ten minutes, which were enough for couple of answers. Don't you agree those answers better be part of the first question?

Comment: @CRUSADER : Why do you think that the accepted answer of first question is not a superset of accepted answer of the second ?

Comment: **This question is not duplicate.** The earlier is question is towards benefits to be given to people who find duplicates and this is about the new point policy for answers on duplicate question.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Search keywords matters... In reference to the link example you posted above, if I were a new user, I would google like this.. `Difference between == and ===` b'coz thats a good simple query I would ask. Now as a consumer I will decide what better solution as both links are available, lowering score points just b'coz its dupe doesn't sounds good..... Gosh!! It seems I am the only one to differ opinion.

Comment: @CRUSADER I'm not saying delete the duplicates or even the answers. Just that we better encourage users to post answers in one central place. Also keep in mind that anonymous visitors are being redirected automatically to the source when trying to visit questions closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

> feature for giving less points for answering on duplicate question be
>   good ?

No,

Duplicate question are good to be around, if it attracts even better answers. More over, many search by different Keywords, they might not end up searching question they desire at first attempt, the link marking as duplicate is good as it is.. To demoralise answerer with less score is not good practice, in that case we will be denying any further improvement.

Comment: Will this not encourage user to, not flag the question as duplicate and just answer it. I am not asking to delete the question. The question will still be available for search.

Comment: I understand your concern, but, we cannot deny that an exceptionally good answer can come in dupes questions. We cannot enforce to post the answerer to answer on question linked, and avoid answer on duplicateed question... denying the rep it deserve will not be good.

Comment: Duplicate questions might be useful for search purposes. I don't see that answers to these questions are useful though. If they add nothing over and above the existing answers on the dupe then they are pointless. And if they do contain something different then this information is now scattered in multiple places.

Comment: @MartinSmith : So is this question closed ? I have never asked anything earlier on Meta.

Comment: @RaviSingh - Sorry, not with you. This question is still open at the moment.